# Unir los círculos de mi lista con líneas

Tags: html, css

Estoy utilizando Font-Awesome para generar una lista con puntos y necesito unir los puntos de la lista html con líneas. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Éste es mi código:

```css
.events {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ressortinfo {
  position: relative;
}

.ressortmenu {
  position: sticky;
  top: 30%;
  float: right;
}

.ressortmenu ul {
  text-align: right;
}

.ressortmenu ul>li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.ressortmenu ul>li i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.ressortmenu ul>li:focus i,
.ressortmenu ul>li:active i {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="ressortmenu">
  <ul class="is-flex events">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Unser Landresort</span>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#historie">
        <span> Denkmal & Historie</span>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Der Or</span>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Tagebuch</span>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Anreise</span>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como puedes lograrlo usando el [pseudo-elemento :after](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after) de CSS

```css
.events {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ressortinfo {
    position: relative;
}

.ressortmenu {
    position: sticky;
    top: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.ressortmenu ul {
    text-align: right;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;

}

.ressortmenu ul > li:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 90%;
    width: 3px;
    background: -webkit-link;
    top: 10px;
    right: 4px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li:last-child:after{
    display: none;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li:focus i, .ressortmenu ul > li:active i  {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ressortmenu">
  <ul class="is-flex events">
      <li><a href="#">
              <span>Unser Landresort</span>
              <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#historie">
              <span> Denkmal & Historie</span>
              <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">
              <span>Der Or</span>
              <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">
              <span>Tagebuch</span>
              <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">
              <span>Anreise</span>
              <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Mejor imposible, no entiendo por que me agarraba el link de font awesome, mira que lo intent...xDD. Gracias